# Call JAR file method in Unity

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, jar

I create a android library in Android Studio and export a jar file. I created 2 class in library. One is `SimpleClass` second is `PlayerClass`.

First I tried the code below it successfully call the method.

**JAVA**

```
package a.b.c.simplelibrary;

public class SimpleClass{
    public static String CallNumber(int nums){
        return "Number is " + nums;
    }
}
```

**In Unity C#**

```
public Text SimpleText;
public void CallNow(){
    AndroidJavaObject jo = new AndroidJavaObject ("a.b.c.simplelibrary.SimpleClass");
    SimpleText.text = jo.CallStatic<string>("CallNumber",123);
}
```

Then I add `extends PlayerClass` in **JAVA** , when I call `CallNow()` in Unity it not return the value anymore.

```
package a.b.c.simplelibrary;

public class SimpleClass extends PlayerClass{
    public static String CallNumber(int nums){
        return "Number is " + nums;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use below function to call flurry "onStartSession" function located in FlurryAgent class. Try this, might work for you too.

```
private AndroidJavaClass cls_FlurryAgent = new AndroidJavaClass("com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent");

public void onStartSession(string apiKey)
{

    Debug.Log ("****** onStartSession " +apiKey);
    using(AndroidJavaClass cls_UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) 
    {
        using(AndroidJavaObject obj_Activity = cls_UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity")) 
        {
            cls_FlurryAgent.CallStatic("onStartSession", obj_Activity, apiKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this don't work try this solution http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/330809/integration-of-jar-file-using-jni.html